# Oracle Listener not starting

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to start my oracle service, but it is not starting. It is showing me :

Following command i am executing : sudo ./lsnrctl start

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 31-JAN-2017 20:31:26

Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Message 1070 not found; No message file for product=network, facility=TNSTNS-12545: Message 12545 not found; No message file for product=network, facility=TNS
 TNS-12560: Message 12560 not found; No message file for product=network, facility=TNS
  TNS-00515: Message 515 not found; No message file for product=network, facility=TNS
   Linux Error: 2: No such file or directory

---

Earlier it was working fine, but after chaning my system name, it stopped working.

Comment: Those messages usually mean you haven't set (and exported) ORACLE_HOME, and maybe other environment variables.

Comment: everything is set. ORACLE_HOME, ORACLE_SID

Comment: I disagree. They may be set, but if so are not exported, or are not set to the right values. Do `export | grep ORA` and check everything is there and correct. If you're really convinced that isn't the problem then show the actual command you run (maybe you're trying to run via sudo/su and losing the environment, or something).

Comment: yes running via sudo

Comment: it is not allowing me to run without sudo

Comment: Please edit the question to show exactly what you are doing. For instance, are you sudo'ing to a shell prompt; or running lsnrctl directly as part of the sudo? Are you trying to start it as yourself, as Oracle, as root; or some other account?

Comment: i am executing : sudo $ORACLE_HOME/bin/lsnrctl start

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134505/discussion-between-nitin-nandankar-and-alex-poole).

Comment: That means you're trying to start/run the listener under root, which isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

try to run like

```
sudo su - oracle -c "ORACLE_SID=your_db_name; ORACLE_HOME=/orahome/Database/db11g; export ORACLE_SID ORACLE_HOME; export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH;$ORACLE_HOME/bin/lsnrctl start"
```

Please change the ORACLE_HOME,your_db_name value according to your environment

Comment: sudo su - oracle -c "ORACLE_SID=db_name; ORACLE_HOME=path; export ORACLE_SID ORACLE_HOME; export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH;$ORACLE_HOME/bin/lsnrctl start"


No it is still not working

Comment: @NitinNandankar - just saying "not working" isn't very helpful - what happens now? (I would do `sudo su oracle` without the dash so it doesn't try to start a login shell; and also you may need to escape the `$`, .i.e. to finish with `... \$ORACLE_HOME/bin/lsnrctl start"` - otherwise that will be interpreted before the sudo call, not within it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep running the listener as root, you can see the error messages using:

```
sudo ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_HOME $ORACLE_HOME/bin/lsnrctl start
```

... which uses your starting (non-root) environment's `$ORACLE_HOME`; otherwise you can set and use that value explicitly:

```
sudo ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/lsnrctl start
```

From chat that gets around the message error and shows you something more useful:

```
Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle. All rights reserved. 

Starting /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/tnslsnr: please wait... 

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production 
System parameter file is /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora 
Log messages written to /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/log/diag/tnslsnr/localhost/listener/alert/log.xml 
Error listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE))) 
TNS-12555: TNS:permission denied 
TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error 
TNS-00525: Insufficient privilege for operation 
Linux Error: 1: Operation not permitted 

Listener failed to start. See the error message(s) above...
```

Your /etc/hosts file links your machine name `sam.samson` to localhost/127.0.0.1, and also from chat your listener contains:

```
LISTENER = 
(DESCRIPTION_LIST = 
(DESCRIPTION = 
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE)) 
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = sam.samson)(PORT = 1521)) 
) 
)
```

As the error message refers to EXTPROC_FOR_XE, and removing that line apparently allows the TCP port to start, Oracle seems to have that linked to the old host name (which now doesn't resolve properly), or something along those lines. You could probably change the key name to something new, but removing it completely may be OK for you.

---

It isn't necessary, or really a good idea, to run any Oracle processes as root. It's normal to have a dedicated `oracle` account, and `dba` group. But you will have a lot of log files etc. that are now owned y root, so in order to change to run under a different account you would need to shut everything down, remove or change the ownership of all the relevant files, and then restart things under the right account.

---

Your database *may* continue to try to register against the old name. If `lsnrctl services` doesn't show the XE service, after starting the database or issuing `alter database register`, that may be the next problem. If you log in locally through SQL*Plus (by setting ORACLE_SID, not using a TNS alias) you can check what `show parameters listener` shows, and if `LOCAL_LISTENER` is referring to the old machine name, change it to match the new name. It may also be using a TNS alias for the listener, so make sure your `tnsnames.ora` is also up-to-date. Or it may now just work.

Answer (score -1):

The walk through at https://youtu.be/zxyXlYgrzJc makes a good explanation of why the permission error occurs and how to fix it.

Comment: Could be a comment, no ?